# get max date DJANGO queryset

Tags: python, django, django-views, django-queryset

I need to extract the max date from a model. I am using aggregate in y queryset

```
fm = Codigo_Corto_Hist.objects.filter(codigo=cod).filter(estado=0).aggregate(Max('fecha_cambio'))
```

but I receive a dict `{'fecha': datetime.date(2015, 1, 1)}` and I only need the value of the date.

There is another way to get the value instead a dictionary or how can I extract the value from the dictionary.

Thanks in advance

Comment: `my_dict["fecha"]` ?

Comment: Thanks @JoranBeasley. I am not familiar with dictionaries. I guess I need to read how to handle dicts

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```py
from django.db.models import Max
fm = Codigo_Corto_Hist.objects.filter(codigo=cod).filter(estado=0).aggregate(Max('fecha_cambio')).values_list('fecha', flat=True)
```